# How to get updated width & height using GlobalKey class after scaling under Transform.scale widget

Tags: flutter, dart

i have the following code which scaling a container

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Ff extends StatefulWidget {
  const Ff({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Ff> createState() => _FfState();
}

class _FfState extends State<Ff> {
  
  double scale = 1.0 ;
  GlobalKey globalKey = GlobalKey();
  double widthAndHeight= 100 ;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Transform.scale(
        scale:scale ,
        child: GestureDetector(
          onScaleUpdate: (detail){
            scale = detail.scale;
            setState(() {});
            RenderBox renderBoxRed = globalKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
            print("width: ${renderBoxRed.size.width}"); // always return old one
            print("height: ${renderBoxRed.size.height}");// always return old one
          },

          child: Center(
            child: Container(
              key: globalKey,
              color: Colors.green,
              width: widthAndHeight,
              height: widthAndHeight,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
      ,
    );
  }
}
```

now to manually get the new `widthAndHeight` value i am multiply the current `widthAndHeight` in `detail.scale` , but when i call RenderBox as mentioned in the example it seem to be not get the updated values and it always return the old value which is `100' why?

and how to get it within RenderBox instead of manually way